# Azure Mobile App Offline Sync - different users

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

#### Current Situation

I created an app that uses the Azure SDK for offline data sync. Sync is working fine including user authentication via Microsoft Account. In Azure I currently use Easy Tables.

#### Problem

Now when I sign in with two different users from two different test devices I can see the same data. My expectation would be that an authenticated user only sees the that was added/updated with his own user ID.

#### Actual Question(s)

Is it by design that all users, that are authenticated, see the data from all other users? So do I have to add some column with a user ID (based on the Microsoft Account ID) and add a condition to the where clause when getting data? (which is strange as all data will be synced to all users then)

I was looking at the docs but couldn't find the right information on that. I didn't add any code to this question yet because it is unclear to me whether this is by design, whether this is something on client side, or whether the config on server side needs to be adjusted for that.

Comment: Have you solved this issue, do you need further assistance?

Answer (score 3):

> Sync is working fine including user authentication via Microsoft Account. In Azure I currently use Easy Tables.

Easy Tables work with Node.js backend, When add tables via Easy Tables, it would help you to build your node.js backend for your added tables automatically. You could leverage "DEVELOPMENT TOOLS > App Service Editor (Preview)" under your mobile app on azure portal to check your backend.

> Is it by design that all users, that are authenticated, see the data from all other users? So do I have to add some column with a user ID (based on the Microsoft Account ID) and add a condition to the where clause when getting data?

For mobile client, you could use [Azure Mobile Client SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/3.1.0) for connecting with your azure mobile app. Assuming that you leverage [Server-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#serverflow) and use the following code for logging with Microsoft Account:

```
MobileServiceUser user=wait MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount);
```

You could retrieve the logged user info via `MobileServiceClient.CurrentUser` and the `CurrentUser` has the property `UserId`. Since you are using Easy Table, you could just add the `UserId` column into each of your user-related tables via Azure Portal. Moreover, you need to change the related SQLite tables in your mobile client app.

For Offline Sync, you could define your OData query as follows for retrieving the items belong to the specified user from the remote table.

```
await todoTable.PullAsync("incsync_ToDoTable_CurrentUser", todoTable.CreateQuery().Where(t => t.UserId=="<userId>");
```

For more details, I recommend you refer to adrian hall's book [Data Access and Offline Sync](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/).

**UPDATE:**

For questions:

**1)** The filter criteria evaluated on the backend and only the rows with the given userId are synced, you could leverage [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for capturing the network trace when handling `pull` operation.

**2)** For a more security approach, you could adjust the data that is being sent to your table controller before it is stored on server side instead of specify the `userId` on your mobile client. For node.js backend, you could modify your code as follows before you inserting the data:

```html
table.insert(function (context) {
  context.item.userId = context.user.id;
  return context.execute();
});
```

For more details, you could refer to [30 DAYS OF ZUMO.V2 (AZURE MOBILE APPS): DAY 6 – PERSONAL TABLES](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/11/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-6-personal-tables/).

Additionally, for C# backend, you could retrieve the `UserId` as follows:

```html
public string UserId
{
    get
    {
        var principal = this.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
        return principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    }
}
```

And modify your action for adding new items as follows:

```html
// POST tables/TodoItem
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostTodoItem(TodoItem item)
{
    item.UserId = UserId;
    TodoItem current = await InsertAsync(item);
    return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
}
```

For more details, you could refer to [Per-User Data](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/projection/#per-user-data).

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm using `LoginAsync` as you said. Two questions: **1)** Where is the filter applied when using `Where(t => t.UserId == "<userId>");`? In other words, is all data synced to the local database and then filtered using this predicate? Or is the filter criteria evaluated on the backend and only the rows with the given userId are synced? **2)** This approach actually means that I have to add the user ID to every instance of my object model, right? So let's say that every TodoItem will get a UserId as soon as it is created. Is there a way to let the SDK handle this field?

Comment: I have updated my answer for explaining your concerned questions, you could refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

To filter the entries per user you have to add a UserId column to your table, which contains the id of the user that owns the item.

Then you can either filter your tables in your client app to only receive the items of the current user.

Or even better apply the filter on the server side, so your client app only receives the items of the user currently logged in.

But I am not sure if this is possible with easy tables, you might have to implement the "full" server version as in the "backend" section of this repo: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts